# Web animations ionic 2 iOS

Tags: ios, angular, animation, ionic2, ionic3

How do you get web animations working in ionic 2 for iOS? I have seen talk about the web animations polyfill, however have not found an easy to follow guide on it's implementation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just like you can see in [Angular2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html)

> Angular animations are built on top of the standard Web Animations API
>   and run natively on browsers that support it.
>   For other browsers, a polyfill is required. Grab web-animations.min.js
>   from GitHub and add it to your page.

So copy the [web-animations js code](https://rawgit.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/master/web-animations.min.js) and paste it in a new file located, for instance, in `assets/js` (new folder).

Then add it to the `index.html` file, as the first script tag from the body:

```
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- Web Animations polyfill -->
  <script src="assets/js/web-animations.js"></script>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
```